# Is there a way to find record in mongo by matching field string with an array of values

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the below record

```
{
   "title": "Kim floral jacquard minidress",
   "designer": "Rotate Birger Christensen"
}
```

How can I find a record in the collection using an array of values. For example, I have the below array values. Because "title" field contains the "floral" value, the record is selected.

```
['floral', 'dresses']
```

The query I am using below doesn't work. :(

```
queryParam = ['floral', 'dresses']

def get_query(queryParam, gender):
        query = {
            "gender": gender
        }

        if (len(queryParam) != 0):
            query["title"] = {"$in": queryParam}

        return query

products_query = get_query(query, gender)
products = mongo.db.products.find(products_query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the previous answer, there's a little bit more to do to get this to work in pymongo. You have to use [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) to get the regex search to work:

```
import re
queryParam = [re.compile('floral'), re.compile('dresses')]
```

Alternatively you could use this approach which removes the need for the `$in` operator:

```
import re
queryParam = [re.compile('floral|dresses')]
```

And once you've done that you don't even need to use re.compile:

```
queryParam = 'floral|dress'
...
            query = {"title": {"$regex": queryParam}}
```

Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do regex search along with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) operator :

```
db.collectionName.find( { title: { $in: [ /floral/, /dresses/ ] } })
```